# fullcalendar fetch events from database using Python web2py

Tags: javascript, python, fullcalendar

I'm using web2py and now I'm fetching all calendar events from db using this code in a view:

```
events: [
    {{for row in rowseventi:}}
        {
            title: '{{=row.evento.titolo}}',
            id: '{{=row.evento.id}}',
            resourceId: '{{=row.evento.risorsa}}',
            start: '{{=row.evento.inizio}}',
            end: '{{=row.evento.fine}}',
            recurring: '{{=row.evento.ricorrenza}}',
            // allDay: false,
            color : '{{=row.evento.colore}}',
            url: '{{=URL('mostra_evento',args=row.evento.id)}}',
       },
       {{pass}}
]
```

It's working perfectly but now I'd like to fetch only events regarding current view using this function https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

```
function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }
```

There are some example using php but I want only use Python and PyDAL.
Can someone give me some examples using only python and JavaScript?

rowseventi it's an array retrieved from controller that contains all events...

When I change the view with "next", "prev" or something else I'd like to fetch the new events based on the dates showed in the view.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to switch the php for python in the examples you've found then you can just swap that directly. The Javascript code wouldn't need to change. What you would need to do in comparison to your structure above though is use a separate AJAX request to fetch your events, so that they can be dynamically updated when the view changes. That's regardless of whatever language your server-side is using.

Comment: Please can you make me a simle example about "separate AJAX request"?

Comment: You can already read about it here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function and it already has an example of the client-side code (albeit using XML data, but actually a version using JSON data would be even simpler). There are also lots of other working examples on this on the fullCalendar site, and many on other websites too including this one. Have you actually tried anything yet? We're not here to write generic examples for you, you can google for those. If you've got some code as your attempt to implement it, which would like help to fix, please show it and we can work on it.

Comment: All you need to do after that is write some python code which will return some JSON event data in the correct format. Again I'm pretty sure if you look online you will be able to find examples of how use python to create a separate endpoint to respond to an ajax call, and how to return JSON, and it's clear from the code above that you already understand the fullcalendar event data structure, so you just need to make it produce that output based on your database data.

Comment: ...even if the example is very simple and not regarding this specific case...thank you!